# "radius" of graph vs. diameter

Tags: graph-theory

Define the diameter of a graph G—denoted diam G—to  be the length of a longest path in G between two different vertices.  For a given vertex v, there is a maximum length of of the non-closed  paths with initial vertex v, and we define the radius of G to be the  smallest of these maximum lengths. More compactly:

Gerstein, Larry J.. Introduction to Mathematical Structures and Proofs (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics) (p. 275). Springer New York. Kindle Edition.

$rad (G) = min_{v\in V}(max_{w\in V}\{d(v,w)\})$

where d(v,w) is the length of the shortest path between vertices v and w

The problem is to prove $diam(G) \le 2 rad(G)$

I seem to have a counter-example: a graph that is a triangle ABE with an edge BC hanging off of it:

[image: graph_with_four_vertices]

According to my calculations, for vertex B, $max\{d(B,w)\}=1$, so the "radius" is one. But the diameter is the length of the path CBAE, which is three. So $d \nleq 2r$

Why am I wrong, or it is possible that I am right?

Comment: Could you rewrite your example? It is a bit confusing. Maybe you could write down all the pairs of edges like $E = \{(A,B), (B,C), (A,E),(B,E)\}$.

Comment: Please check that the graph is correct.

Comment: I haven't seen that book, but in every graph trheory text I've seen, the distance between two vertices, $d(u,v)$, is defined as the length of a ***shortest*** path from $u$ to $v$.  According to the standard definitions, your example graph has radius $1$ and diameter $2$.

Comment: The distance between two vertices is the length of the shortest path between them; the diameter is the longest distance between any two vertices in the graph.  In your example graph, the longest distance is between $C$ and either $A$ or $E$, and is equal to $2$; this is therefore the diameter of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you write
$$ rad(G) = \min_{v\in V} \max_{w\in V} d(v,w)$$
and
$$ diam(G) = \max_{v\in V} \max_{w\in V} d(v,w).$$

Suppose that the diameter is realized by $v',w'$, then $diam(G) = d(v', w')$. Also assume that $rad(G)$ is realized at $v''$, that is, $rad(G) = \max_{w\in V} d(v'',w)$.

By triangle inequality:
$$ d(v',w') \le d(v',v'') + d(v'', w') \le 2\max_{w\in V} d(v'',w) = 2rad(G).$$

Answer (score 1):

The diamter of the graph is the longest of the shortest paths between pairs of points, that is
$$ diam(G) = \max_{v,w\in V} d(v,w)$$
In the case of the graph you showed, $diam(G) = 2$, because the shortest path between C and E is CBE, not CBAE.

Comment: Here is how diameter is defined: "the length of the *longest* path in G between two different vertices." So can that be identified with the *distance*, which is the length of the *shortest* path? Perhaps the author intended the diameter to be the longest distance between two vertices rather than the length of the longest path between two vertices?

Comment: @AnnaNaden, the diameter of a graph is definitely always understood to be the longest distance between any two vertices. If you're reading a source which provides a different definition, that's a mistake.